# Twitter Bootstrap 3.2 Font Matching

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a website using Twitter Bootstrap 3.2, but I a having trouble getting the fonts to match between my paragraphs and lists.  For instance, this code would have a different font in the list versus the paragraph:

```
<ul class="inline-list">
<li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
<p>This font does not match the list's font/size</p>
```

I feel like there should be an easy solution to this, but I don't think I'm using the right terms in my search, because I haven't found anything.  I appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
ul.inline-list p, ul.inline-list li
{
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Comment: And to clarify, this would make most sense to put in the page header rather than modifying the Bootstrap CSS file?

Comment: you are right. no need to modify bootstrap css file.

Comment: Last question: This also modifies the style of the navbar which also has a list.  How can I just modify the style within a specific class of div?

Comment: I have updated my answer with specific element. So now it will affect only this block.